Whats the purpose of slots in wings?
As mentioned by the person in this video, what's purpose of the slots in this Ray Stits Sky Baby airplane?

(source)

The purpose of a slot is to correct the direction of airflow over that portion of the wing at high angles of attack, to delay the onset of flow separation which leads to a stall.
Putting slots near the wingtips helps prevent a stall which starts at the wingtip first. That sort of stall is particularly dangerous because the lever arm for lift generated in the tipmost portion of the wing is equal to the whole length of the wing. Any change in lift there will produce a particularly strong roll moment which will tend to flip the whole plane over on its side and into a spin.

You'll notice here that the upper wing is mounted at a higher angle of attack.
Curiously, the wings are in a "reverse stagger", meaning the rear one will stall first.
The plane was made to be the smallest in the world, but probably after noticing this design "oopsy", the slot was added to improve safety.
Oh, if they had only made it a monoplane with folding wings.

are you sure it's not some perspective bias that seems to show greater incidence on upper wing? unable to find full scale aircraft plans, it seems rc plans show identical incidence on both wings or even higher incidence for the lower wing.

@user721108 there are pictures in reference "here".  Have a look.

have a look at pictures 2 and 7 I still think you were fooled by the vanishing point / short focal. have a look here

@user721108 that's on paper, rather than the actual plane, but I see your point.  See 2nd photo down on the right.

it seems no plans exist for the full scale machine. you can read about how quarter scale plans were made 30 years later and download those here
